# How to add multiple classes to remoting-config.xml?

Tags: java, flex4, blazeds

I have a question, how do I add multiple classes in remoting-config.xml file?
I am using flex, java, blazeDS.
By default it looks something like that:

```
<destination id="someID">
    <properties>
        <source>com.package.ClassName</source>
        <scope>application</scope>
    </properties>
</destination>
```

If I add multiple `<source>` tags I get an error. Of course I know I can add multiple destinations for each class, but then it will take too much space. So maybe anyone know any other shorter way of doing it?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't destinations represent services?  How many services could you possibly have?  Are you sure you are trying to list the correct thing?  If you're trying to list the classes that you want to serialize/deserialize I believe that goes somewhere else.  In fact, I don't even think you have to list those.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am doing the right thing. Yes destinations do represent services, but <source> represent classes which I want to serialize and there I can put only one class. I found some article http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/multiclassjavaadapter/ but it didn't work some how.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare one class per destination, and in most of the cases I also think that'
s the right approach. If you really don't want to do that you should try to use Sujit adapter (and to a debug session to check why does not work), or you can write your own adapter.